# Different data when printing and writing to file

Tags: java, file-io

There is a stream of data which is sent from server. I need to store this byte stream into a file. The problem is the data which I output to console and the one which I store in a file are different. Seems like there is a change in format of data when I stored in a file.

Here is the program:

```
try
{
    System.out.println("My Address is "+serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
    Socket server = serverSocket.accept();      // return a new socket
    System.out.println("Connected to client "+server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    inputStream = server.getInputStream();
    in = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    int curi;
    byte cur;
    byte[] curBytes = null;
    int length = 0;
    System.out.println("Before while loop");
    while((curi = in.read())!=-1 && count!=500)
    {
        System.out.println(count+" Reading some data");
        //out.write(curi);
        cur = (byte)curi;
        bytes.add(cur);
        curBytes = getPrimativeArray(bytes);

        String curBytesString = new String(curBytes, "UTF-8");
        count++;
    }
    int i=0;
    for(byte b : bytes)
    {
        System.out.print(b+"  ");
        curBytes[i] = b;
        i++;
    }
    out.write(curBytes);

    server.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I print  using **System.out.print(b+"  ");** and the one I store in **curBytes[]** are the same thing. But when I compare the console and file output, they are different.

**Console output:** `0  0  113  -100  -126  -54  0  32  14  1  0  0  1  -58  60  54  0  3  63  -2  85  74  -81  -88  0  9  1  24  85  74  -81  -48  0  13  65  -113  85  74  -81  -88  0  12  125  -126  85  74  -81  -88  0  13  21  97  85  74  -81  -88  0  13  31  19  85  74  -81  -48  0  13  42  24  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  32  0  7  -100  0  -5  6  -128  0  -56  29  -127  23  112  -1  -1  0  0  64  0  1  -121  28  115  105  112  58  43  49  52  50  50  50  48  57  57  57  49  53  64  111  110  101  46  97  116  116  46  110  101  116  28  115  105  112  58  43  49  52  50  50  50  48  57  57  57  54  53  64  111  110  101  46  97  116  116  46  110  101  116  37  50  57  54  53  45  49  53  48  53  48  54  50  51  50  55  48  50  45  50  48  53  48  54  54  50  55  54  54  64  48  48  55  56  48  48  49  49  16  32  1  5  6  64  0  0  0  32  16  0  0  0  120  0  17  16  32  1  24  -112  16  1  46  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  1  -113  0  4  0  33  -64  -42  0  91  5  8  0  9  0  -56  0  0  0  15  3  85  74  -81  -88  0  12  -120  -28  8  0  9  0  -56  0  0  0  15  3  85  74  -81  -88  0  12  -44  -39  8  0  4  0  -56  0  0  1  11  3  85  74  -81  -88  0  9  1  24  8  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  85  74  -81  -88  0  13  31  19  8  0  1  0  -56  0  0  0  6  3  85  74  -81  -48  0  13  42  24  -64  34  4  24  9  89  83  73  80  47  50  46  48  47  84  67  80  32  91  50  48  48  49  58  53  48  54  58  52  48  48  48  58  48  58  50  48  49  48  58  48  58  55  56  58  49  49  93  58  49  51  55  48  59  98  114  97  110  99  104  61  122  57  104  71  52  98  75  50  57  48  45  48  48  55  56  48  48  49  49  45  48  48  48  102  45  52  52  49  57  55  49  52  48  51  3  85  74  -81  -88  0  12  -120  -28  127  83  73  80  47  50  46  48  47  84  67  80  32  91  50  48  48  49  58  53  48  54  58  52  48  48  48  58  48  58  50  48  49  48  58  48  58  55  56  58  49  49  93  58  49  51  55  48  59  114  101  99  101  105  118  101  100  61  50  48  48  49`

**File Output:** `^@^@q<9c><82>Ê^@ ^N^A^@^@^AÆ<6^@^C?þUJ¯¨^@      ^A^XUJ¯Ð^@^MA<8f>UJ¯¨^@^L}<82>UJ¯¨^@^M^UaUJ¯¨^@^M^_^SUJ¯Ð^@^M*^X^@^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^G<9c>^@û^F<80>^@È^]<81>^Wpÿÿ^@^@@^@^A<87>^\sip:+14222099915@one.att.net^\sip:+14222099965@one.att.net%2965-150506232702-2050662766@00780011^P ^A^E^F@^@^@^@ ^P^@^@^@x^@^Q^P ^A^X<90>^P^A.^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^F^A<8f>^@^D^@!ÀÖ^@[^E^H^@ ^@È^@^@^@^O^CUJ¯¨^@^L<88>ä^H^@  ^@È^@^@^@^O^CUJ¯¨^@^LÔÙ^H^@^D^@È^@^@^A^K^CUJ¯¨^@        ^A^X^H^@^E^@^@^@^@^@^@^CUJ¯¨^@^M^_^S^H^@^A^@È^@^@^@^F^CUJ¯Ð^@^M*^XÀ"^D^X        YSIP/2.0/TCP [2001:506:4000:0:2010:0:78:11]:1370;branch=z9hG4bK290-00780011-000f-441971403^CUJ¯¨^@^L<88>ä^?SIP/2.0/TCP [2001:506:4000:0:2010:0:78:11]:1370;received=2001`

Please let me know at what step I'm making a mistake.

Comment: what type of data are you sending from the other end?

Comment: Note that `curBytes = getPrimativeArray(bytes);` doesn't look right inside that loop. It should be after the loop, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers here tell you to use a `PrintWriter` or a `FileWriter` instead of the `FileOutputStream` but I'm fairly sure that this is **not** what you want.

Your problem is that you're writing raw bytes to a file and then reading it back as characters and comparing that to byte values represented as characters and then printed with `System.out`.

Let's take a look at what happens when you print a byte with the value `65` (or `01000001` in binary).

When you use `System.out.print` you will invoke [`PrintStream.print(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28int%29) with the integer value of `65` which will in turn print the characters `6` and `5` to the terminal.

When you use `out.write` you will invoke [`FileOutputStream.write(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte[]%29) which will write the bits `01000001` to the file.

Later, when you check the contents of the file your tool will try to interpret this byte as a character and it will most likely use the [ASCII encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) to do so (even if you're using Unicode as your default encoding this is likely what will happen since Unicode is a superset of ASCII). This results in the character `A` being printed.

If you want to view the output file in a way similar to what you've printed with `System.out.print` you can use the following command on linux:

```
$ hexdump -e '/1 "%i "' <file>
```

Example:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS \n \l
$ hexdump -e '/1 "%i "' /etc/issue
85 98 117 110 116 117 32 49 50 46 48 52 46 53 32 76 84 83 32 92 110 32
92 108 10 *
```

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was wrong, so I am editing this because I made the assumption that you could write out a string to the FileOutputStream, but I don't think that is the case. FileOutputStream is only used for byte streams, so you've got to stick to that format when writing out to the file.

If you hold the data in a buffer[array], and then write those bytes out to a file that you have created using the output stream, it should work. I found this document that might be helpful.

The main idea is that somewhere in your code, the byte array isn't getting written to the file correctly. Perhaps its just a matter of adding the close() method.

```
out.close();
server.close();
```

[reading and writing files in java](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html)

Here is the section I found useful.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String [] args) {

    // The name of the file to create.
    String fileName = "temp.txt";

    try {
        // Put some bytes in a buffer so we can
        // write them. Usually this would be
        // image data or something. Or it might
        // be unicode text.
        String bytes = "Hello theren";
        byte[] buffer = bytes.getBytes();

        FileOutputStream outputStream =
            new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        // write() writes as many bytes from the buffer
        // as the length of the buffer. You can also
        // use
        // write(buffer, offset, length)
        // if you want to write a specific number of
        // bytes, or only part of the buffer.
        outputStream.write(buffer);

        // Always close files.
        outputStream.close();       

        System.out.println("Wrote " + buffer.length + 
            " bytes");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error writing file '"
            + fileName + "'");
        // Or we could just do this:
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The console (`System.out`) is a `PrintWriter`, while the file output is a `FileOutputStream`.

The basic difference between `Stream` and `Writer`: **Streams** are supposed to manipulate "raw data", like numbers taken directly from binary format, while **writers** are used to manipulate "human-readable data", transforming all the data you write.

For example, the `6` int is different from the `6` character. When you use a stream, you write directly the int, while with a writer, the data wrriten is transformed into the character.

Then, if you want your file output to be the same as your console output, do not use `FileOutputStream`, but instead, use [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), and it's method [write(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)).

**How to make this work:**

1 - replace `out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");` by `out = new FileWriter("output.txt");`

2 - replace `out.write(curBytes);` by:

```
for (byte b : curBytes) {
  out.write(b + " ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use [IOUtils.copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) and use a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)
to wrap your InputStream. 
The output stream should obviously be [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) 
I hope this helps

Comment: I would like to state it's easy to implement such a copy method on your own. If you cannot use 3rd party libraries, just look at the source and implement yourself.

Comment: How does this answer the question?